# unexpected type '<unnamed-tag>'

Tags: c

I am converting C- code based program into Unicode visual studio 2008 on windows 7 64 it OS. I have converted all the non unicode function into unicode successfully. But only getting compiler error in some c- code based functions as given below:

```
struct ref_pages *rfl_scan_ref_list( short mode, short class, short element, _TCHAR **refdata )
```

In the above fuunction, class is defined as a variable parameter. When we will convert this function into Unicode saying:

```
error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type '<unnamed-tag>'
'class' : missing tag name
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use "class" as a variable name.  You're using a c++ compiler and "class" is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in the lines you posted.

Apparently you're not using a C compiler for your C code. **Why?** Use a C compiler for C code; a Pascal compiler for Pascal code; a Lisp compiler for Lisp code; etc ...

I believe Visual Studio has an option to make it a C compiler. You need to find that option and set it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, you're using a C++ compiler and `class` is a reserved keyword in C++. To force VS2008 to act as C compiler, right click on your project name, select **Properties**. Then browse to **Configuration Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced** and then change the **Compile As** option to **Compile as C Code**.

Comment: I have checked project setting in my old code "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)" and I was wondering there is no comipler error for the above issue. What is the reason?

Comment: @Annie: I'm not sure, maybe that version of Visual Studio wasn't very strict about enforcing rules.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved keyword in C++. you should use another variable name.

Comment: Actualy I dont want to disturb my old code which has been based on C- code. I just trying to convert into unicode VC 8.